# How do you get your path in Octave (on Windows)?

Tags: windows, path, octave

I used `addpath(pwd)` to get my .m files working in my projects directory. When I close the window and start a new window, the path I just added is gone. But the files still run.

Is it in my path or not? How do I see the directories I have added to my path?

Also, `.` is the first entry I see from `path`. Does that mean I don't need to add any directories because it will always search the current directory first?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically, yes.

You can add a directory to the search path using `addpath()`, but as you know, it only exists for the current session and is reset when you restart Octave. If you want a path to survive between sessions, add it to your `octaverc`, a script file that gets run whenever a new session gets started. Example path to `octaverc` file is:

```
C:\Octave\3.2.4_gcc-4.4.0\share\octave\site\m\startup
```

Since `.` is in your path by default, Octave will search your current directory for any function files that it needs. Using `addpath(pwd)` is somewhat useless if you're just going to stay in the same directory. However, there are some cases where it'd be useful, if for example you have a directory that contains your functions, and another one that has the data that you're working on: you could start in the functions directory, do `addpath(pwd)`, and then `cd` to the data directory while still being able to use your functions.

Comment: I wonder whether there is any way to include all the sub-directories so that we wouldn't have to add all the paths we need.

Something like `/home/user/Documents/Octave/*`

Answer (score 2):

You can create batch file, which will start Octave with your directory path. Please see example below:

```
octave-3.6.4.exe -p "C:\MyOctaveDiretory"

 -p means addpath()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
addpath(pwd); savepath();
```

Done.

Comment: I hope you've noticed you only answered a part of what he is asking... Can you help with the rest as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug in Octave (I use version 4.0.3 on Windows). When I create a new file in current path, this can't be called by Octave ("error: 'foo' undefined near line 1 column 1"). If I restart Octave, it works. This addpath(pwd) trick helps me a lot (before I unsuccessfully tried rehash() and cd elsewhere and back again).

If you had the same problem, the reason for the symptom might be:

1. Start Octave.
2. Create newfile.m.
3. Call newfile - fails since Octave did not register its existence.
4. addpath(pwd) - causes Octave to register it.
5. Close Octave
6. Start Octave - now pwd is gone from path, but newfile.m is registered at startup.
7. call newfile - works

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem in adding path where the path was added by using addpath command directly in Octave GUI (Command Window). The path added was being shown in console window but none of the functions worked.
The problem was solved by changing the path directory from Windows directory to some other direction where OS is not installed.