# Octave error filename undefined near line x column y

Tags: octave

I am trying to run an Octave file which is in the working directory, but I get an error. Octave does not seem to recognize that it should run the file.

```
unknown@unknown> dir
.                       ex1data1.txt            plotData.m
..                      ex1data2.txt            submit.m
computeCost.m           featureNormalize.m      submitWeb.m
computeCostMulti.m      gradientDescent.m       warmUpExercise.m
ex1.m                   gradientDescentMulti.m
ex1_multi.m             normalEqn.m

unknown@unknown> ex1
error: `ex1' undefined near line 21 column 1

unknown@unknown> ex1.m
error: `ex1' undefined near line 22 column 1
```

Can anyone advise how I can run the ex1 file?

Comment: You taking the machine learning class on coursera?

Comment: @Neil Yes, I was taking that course :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This fixed the problem [at least for me,  on **Windows**]:

Entering the following command in Octave:

```
>addpath(pwd)
```

before calling the script:

```
>ex1
```

There is more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936457/how-do-you-get-your-path-in-octave-on-windows).

Answer (score 4):

Octave (I'm on 4.0.3) will return this error (undefined near line 1 column 1) if you have a capital letter in your path anywhere. For example, if you have a folder on Windows, with the name d:/Myfolder/octave  and then you write this:

cd d:/myfolder/octave (note the small "m")

Then octave will fail.

You have to write exactly the windows path:

cd d:/Myfolder/octave

and octave will be fine

Answer (score 1):

You need to also save the file as "fileName.m"

Octave doesn't recognize 'fileName.M'. It has to be a lower-case '.m' extension

Answer (score 1):

For me, it helped naming file the same as function - it is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your file extension should me .m only sometimes rich text editor or other editors add their own extension behind .m so it becomes like .m.rtf for example.
2. In Coursera tutorial the file name is All small case and Function name is camelcased, but that only offered a warning does not throw the error.
3. You should be in the same directory where the .m function file actually exists alternatively as suggested by @tucson above you can use addpath(pwd) to get access from any directory.